# custom unique validation in laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

I have a collection where need to validate below two row as unique

```
['id1', 'id2', '']
['id1', 'id2', 'abc']
```

This is unique for me. How can I apply custom unique logic in laravel collection?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```php
$array1 = ['id1', 'id2', ''];
$array2 = ['id1', 'id2', 'abc'];
$data = collect($array1);
$data = $data->merge($array2);
$data = $data->unique();
```

Comment: I don't have array, I have collection. just gave example above

Comment: You can always do: `$data = $firstCollection->merge($secondCollection);`